# Java mutual dependency with interfaces set in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, interface, dependencies

I have 2 classes that rely on each other and they both have their respective interfaces. However, I cannot setup the constructor on both classes cleanly. In short, one class needs to be instantiated before the other class gets instantiated.

```
Class A implements IA {
    public A(IB b) {
        myBclass = b;
    }
    private IB myBclass;
}

Class B implements IB {
    public B(IA a) {
        myAclass = a;
    }
    private IA myAclass;
}

static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A(null);
    B b = new B(a);
    a.setB(b); // how can I avoid doing this
}
```

I would like to avoid setting member variables outside the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can have one construct the other.

```
class A implements IA {
    private IB myBclass;
    public A() {
        myBclass = new B(this);
    }
    // etc.
}
class B implements IB {
    private IA myAclass;
    public B(IA a){
        myAclass = a;
    }
    // etc.
}
```

That way you don't have to alter them after construction.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    A a = new A();
    B b = a.getB();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to make sure that A's B is actually this B? In Main, it would be possible to do `IB b = new B( new A() ));` which would result in a B->A->B' where B != B' ...

Comment: @Fildor Yes, completely possible. So you probably wouldn't want to do that.

Comment: Yes, of course _I_ wouldn't but maybe some other Dev will. Would you recommend just leaving a comment to not do this for other Devs or enforce it in code by throwing some exception for example?

Comment: @Fildor you cant do that if you make the default constructors private
i.e.     class A{ privateA() }

Comment: @Fildor something like `if(a.getB() != this) { throw new Exception("Blah"); }` in `B's` constructor?

Comment: Simply throwing an exception from the constructor can't solve this problem. Either `A.myBclass` is set first, or `B.myAclass` is set first. They can't each verify the other.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Exactly. I was just wondering if you guys would recommend doing this. See, I had the experience that some other Devs used my code and frankly - not like I intended. Then they got weird errors and *I* had to clean up the mess. If I had installed such an exception in the first place, they would have known "oh, I am not supposed to do this obviously ... " - They were pretty unexperienced, but still - what's clear to *me* is not necessarily clear to others at once.

Comment: @khelwood "Simply throwing an exception from the constructor can't solve this problem." - I agree and fully understand that. I thought of it as kind of "killswitch" if used improperly. Of course, you'd have to fix the code.